# Jquery plugin not working on append content

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, select, append

I'm using the selectpicker from http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select
The plugin is initiated by this code.

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

When I want to add content with ".append" this selectpicker doesn't seem to work on a select box. Does anybody has an idea how to solve this?

```
jQuery(function(){
var highlight_counter = 1;
jQuery('a.add-highlight').click(function(event){
    jQuery('table.highlights').append('<tr class="report-line"><td class="float-left margin-top"><input type="text" class="form-control-form input-tiny margin-right" placeholder="mm"></td><td class="report-players-alt float-left margin-bottom margin-top"><span class="report-players-icon bowders-left"><i class="fa fa-thumb-tack"></i></span><select id="highlights' + highlight_counter + '" class="selectpicker margin-bottom bowders-right"><option value="0">Select a highlight</option><option value="goal">Goal</option><option value="yellow">Yellow Card</option><option value="red">Red Card</option><option value="sub">Substitution</option></select><div id="msgbox' + highlight_counter + '"></div></td><td class="row-remove-alt pointer"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></td></tr>');

    highlight_counter++;
});
jQuery("table.highlights").on('click','.row-remove-alt',function(event){
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

});

Thank you very much!

S

Answer (score 0):

You will have to refresh/update your selectpicker after appending the options. Try `.selectpicker('refresh')`

Comment: Share a working link. It will help us understand your problem better.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function(){
        var highlight_counter = 1;
        jQuery('a.add-highlight').click(function(event){
        jQuery('table.highlights').append('<tr class="report-line"><td class="float-left margin-top"><input type="text" class="form-control-form input-tiny margin-right" placeholder="mm"></td><td class="report-players-alt float-left margin-bottom margin-top"><span class="report-players-icon bowders-left"><i class="fa fa-thumb-tack"></i></span><select id="highlights' + highlight_counter + '" class="selectpicker margin-bottom bowders-right"><option value="0">Select a highlight</option><option value="goal">Goal</option><option value="yellow">Yellow Card</option><option value="red">Red Card</option><option value="sub">Substitution</option></select><div id="msgbox' + highlight_counter + '"></div></td><td class="row-remove-alt pointer"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></td></tr>');
        highlight_counter++;
        return false;
    });
    jQuery("table.highlights").on('click','.row-remove-alt',function(event){
        $(this).closest('tr').remove(); return false;
    });
});
```

Add return false at the end of the functions to prevent the default action

Comment: Add $('#highlights'+highlight_counter).selectpicker(); before highlight_counter++;